# Why are Pakistani and Virginia pronounced Packistani and Virginea not /peɪkəˈstanē/ and /vərˈjaɪnyə

Tags: pronunciation

While a u sound in nudity and student is oo, a "a" Taki is o, and more. Why isn't both Pakistani and Virginia pronounced the way it is?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _a "a" Taki is o and more_. _Pakistan_ is the transliteration of the country's Urdu name, and pronounced  in English approximately as its citizens say it.

Answer (score 3):

There are no rules for pronunciations, only guidelines.

Pakistani isn't /peɪkəˈstanē/  because it is  /ˌpæ.kɪˈstɑː.ni/ or /ˌpɑː.kɪˈstɑː.ni/. (with some dialect and individual variation) There can be no deeper reason than this.